# Application Instance on MC

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, instance, multiple-instances, motorola

On MC 65 / 55, whatever clicking A.exe file more than once, system points to the same running A.exe. (But at one time, on MC 65, there were 3 A.exe shown in Task Manager.)

But on MC 3000, system opens A.exe, depends on clicking.

Please share me why it is.

Comment: Here is [**one more source**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/Video/bb943002). Thank you, @ctacke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Mobile's version of the Compact Framework has a "feature" that attempts to prevent multiple executions of the same application.  I say "attempts" because [the mechanism used by the EE to enforce it](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/netcfagl.aspx) is flawed and if you launch the app a couple times in quick succession you can get multiple instances anyway.

Under Windows CE (which the MC3000 is) the feature isn't used at all - it's up to you to implement it.  IMO, that's a better route anyway, as you get to implement it how you want in your app - including possibly passing command-line parameters, plus you have the potential to actually [do it right with a mutex](http://www.nesser.org/blog/archives/56).